# jquery not working from external symfony bundle

Tags: jquery, css, symfony, twig

Hello im trying to implement this symfony 3.4 RatingBundle

https://github.com/blackknight467/StarRatingBundle

i got this result

[image: pic one]

the css working perfect but the stars are non clickable so the problem that there is no link between the js and the stars

this is my code  #update : i have put the js code in the twig page to make the code more clear.

html.twig

```
   {%  extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    <h1>Lists of Posts !</h1>

    <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
        <div class="container">

            <h2>Search A Post !!</h2>

            <div class="sidebar-search">

                <div class="input-group custom-search-form">

                    <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here">
                </div>
                <!-- /input-group -->
            </div>
            <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#"> resultats de recherche<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level" id="entitiesNav">
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul><br><br><br><br>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js') }}"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">



                $(function(){

                    // $( '.rating' ).click(function() {
                    //     alert(parseInt($(this).find('input').val()));
                    // });


                    var labelWasClicked = function labelWasClicked(){

                        var input = $(this).siblings().filter('input');
                        if (input.attr('disabled')) {
                            return;
                        }
                        input.val($(this).attr('data-value'));

                    }

                    var turnToStar = function turnToStar(){
                        if ($(this).find('input').attr('disabled')) {
                            return;
                        }
                        var labels = $(this).find('div');
                        labels.removeClass();
                        labels.addClass('star');
                    }

                    var turnStarBack = function turnStarBack(){
                        var rating = parseInt($(this).find('input').val());

                        if (rating > 0) {
                            var selectedStar = $(this).children().filter('#rating_star_'+rating)
                            var prevLabels = $(selectedStar).nextAll();
                            prevLabels.removeClass();
                            prevLabels.addClass('star-full');
                            selectedStar.removeClass();
                            selectedStar.addClass('star-full');
                        }
                    }

                    $('.star, .rating-well').click(labelWasClicked);
                    $('.rating-well').each(turnStarBack);
                    $('.rating-well').hover(turnToStar,turnStarBack);

                });
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    var searchRequest = null;
                    $("#search").keyup(function() {
                        var minlength = 1;
                        var that = this;
                        var value = $(this).val();
                        var entitySelector = $("#entitiesNav").html('');
                        if (value.length >= minlength ) {
                            if (searchRequest != null)
                                searchRequest.abort();
                            searchRequest = $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: "{{ path('ajax_search') }}",
                                data: {
                                    'q' : value
                                },
                                dataType: "text",
                                success: function(msg){
                                    //we need to check if the value is the same
                                    if (value===$(that).val()) {
                                        var result = JSON.parse(msg);
                                        $.each(result, function(key, arr) {
                                            $.each(arr, function(id, value) {
                                                if (key === 'posts') {
                                                    if (id !== 'error') {
                                                        console.log(value[1]);
                                                        entitySelector.append('<li><b>'+value[1]+'</b><a href="/pidev_symfony-officiel/web/app_dev.php/livre/detailedlivre/'+id+'">'+'<img src="/pidev_symfony-officiel/web/livimages/'+value[0]+'" style="width: 50px; height: 70px"/>'+'</a></li>');
                                                    } else {
                                                        entitySelector.append('<li class="errorLi">'+value+'</li>');
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <div class="post-container">
                <div class="row">


                    <section class="featured section-padding">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12 text-center">
                                    <div class="heading">
                                        <h1 class="section-title">Livres</h1>
                                        <br>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                {% for livre in livres %}

                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="featured-box">
                                            <figure>
                                                  {#<img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset('livimages/' ~ livre.image) }}" style="width: 270px;height: 350px">#}
                                                <a href="{{ path('detailed_livre',{'id': livre.idLivre}) }}"><img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset('livimages/' ~ livre.image) }}" style="width: 50px; height: 70px" alt=""></a>
                                            </figure>
                                            <div class="content-wrapper">
                                                <div class="feature-content">
                                                    <h4>{{ livre.libelle }}</a></h4>
                                                    <p class="listing-tagline">{{ livre.description|trim }}</p>

                                                    <p class="rating">{{ '4'|rating }}</p>


                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                {% endfor %}

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </section>



                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}


{% endblock %}
```

php :

```
<?php

namespace Esprit\LoisirBundle\Form;

use blackknight467\StarRatingBundle\Form\RatingType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class LivreType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('libelle')
            ->add('description' ,TextareaType::class)
            ->add('file')
            ->add('auteur')
            ->add('url')
            ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, array('label' => 'Type',
                'choices' => array(' PDF' => 'pdf',
                    'Audio' => 'audio'),
                'required' => true,))
            ->add('categorie', ChoiceType::class, array('label' => 'Categorie',
                'choices' => array(
                    ' Historique' => 'historique',
                    ' Biographique' => 'biographique',
                    ' Politique' => 'politique',
                    ' Voyages' => 'Voyages',
                    'Jeunesse' => 'Jeunesse'),
                    'required' => true,))
        ->add('rating', RatingType::class, [
        'label' => 'Rating'
    ]);

    }/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Esprit\LoisirBundle\Entity\Livre'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'esprit_loisirbundle_livre';
    }


}
```

controller.php

```
<?php

namespace Esprit\LoisirBundle\Controller;

use Esprit\LoisirBundle\Entity\Livre;
use Esprit\LoisirBundle\Entity\Utilisateur;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

/**
 * Livre controller.
 *
 */
class LivreController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all livre entities.
     *
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        //$livres = $em->getRepository('EspritLoisirBundle:Livre')->findAll();
        $livres = $em->getRepository('EspritLoisirBundle:Livre')->findBy([], ['idLivre' => 'DESC']);

        return $this->render('livre/index.html.twig', array('livres' => $livres));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new livre entity.
     *
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        /* ====== sesssion try */

        $user = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
        $user1=new Utilisateur();
        $user1= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Utilisateur::class) ->find($user->getId());

        /* ====== sesssion try */

        $livre = new Livre();
        $form = $this->createForm('Esprit\LoisirBundle\Form\LivreType', $livre);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            /* ===== session */
            $livre->setIdUtilisateur($user1);
            /* ===== session */

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            /* =====Image Up====== */
            $livre -> uploadPicture();
            /* =====Image Up====== */
            $em->persist($livre);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('livre_show', array('idLivre' => $livre->getIdlivre()));
        }

        return $this->render('livre/new.html.twig', array(
            'livre' => $livre,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a livre entity.
     *
     */
    public function showAction(Livre $livre)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($livre);

        return $this->render('livre/show.html.twig', array(
            'livre' => $livre,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing livre entity.
     *
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Livre $livre)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($livre);
        $editForm = $this->createForm('Esprit\LoisirBundle\Form\LivreType', $livre);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('livre_edit', array('idLivre' => $livre->getIdlivre()));
        }

        return $this->render('livre/edit.html.twig', array(
            'livre' => $livre,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a livre entity.
     *
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, Livre $livre)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($livre);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($livre);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('livre_index');
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a livre entity.
     *
     * @param Livre $livre The livre entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm(Livre $livre)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('livre_delete', array('idLivre' => $livre->getIdlivre())))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }

    public function showdetailedAction($id)
    {
        $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $liv=$em->getRepository('EspritLoisirBundle:Livre')->find($id);
        return $this->render('@EspritLoisir/Livre/detailedpost.html.twig', array(
            'libelle'=>$liv->getLibelle(),
            'description'=>$liv->getDescription(),
            'image'=>$liv->getImage(),
            'auteur'=>$liv->getAuteur(),
            'url'=>$liv->getUrl(),
            'type'=>$liv->getType(),
            'categorie'=>$liv->getCategorie(),
            //'posts'=>$liv,
            'comments'=>$liv,
            'idLivre'=>$liv->getIdLivre()
        ));
    }


    public function listlivreAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $livres=$em->getRepository('EspritLoisirBundle:Livre')->findAll();
        return $this->render('livre/list.html.twig', array(
            "livres" =>$livres
        ));
    }

    public function searchAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $requestString = $request->get('q');
        $livres =  $em->getRepository('EspritLoisirBundle:Livre')->findEntitiesByString($requestString);
        if(!$livres) {
            $result['posts']['error'] = "0 books given ";
        } else {
            $result['posts'] = $this->getRealEntities($livres);
        }
        return new Response(json_encode($result));
    }
    public function getRealEntities($livres){
        foreach ($livres as $livres){
            $realEntities[$livres->getIdLivre()] = [$livres->getImage(),$livres->getLibelle()];
        }
        return $realEntities;
    }
}
```

css :

https://github.com/blackknight467/StarRatingBundle/blob/master/Resources/public/css/rating.css

js :

https://github.com/blackknight467/StarRatingBundle/blob/master/Resources/public/js/rating.js

my main problem is  how to call this in the html page

```
$('.star, .rating-well').click(labelWasClicked);
    $('.rating-well').each(turnStarBack);
    $('.rating-well').hover(turnToStar,turnStarBack);
```

test  in new.html.twig as requested :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/public/css/rating.css') }}" />
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/public/js/rating.js') }}"></script>
    <h1>Livre creation</h1>

    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    {{ form_end(form) }}
    {{ '2'|rating }}

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('livre_index') }}">Back to the list</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to run js code against an item with a given class? This question is quite vague, would you please be able to update it?

Comment: how can i call the js code on the stars with the right class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand how the [library](https://github.com/blackknight467/StarRatingBundle) works correctly then I think that the `rating` twig filter is used to just display the rating.

In order to actually rate you need to place the `RatingType` in a form (like you did) display the form, and then submit it and save results.

In the twig file you've provided you seem to be looping over a collection of `Livre` (I assume) entities, and in that context you can only view the rating of a livre. For now I see you have a hardcoded `4` in `{{ '4'|rating }}` there, but I guess at some point it should become `{{ livre.rating|rating }}` (assuming you will keep the rating score in the `Livre` entity under `rating` column) to reflect the actual rating score.

The javascript code that you've added to the twig file is misplaced. Like I've mentioned, you seem to be in "viewing" context. To actually use this script to give rating you need to be on a page where `LivreType` form is displayed (as it is the one that holds `RatingType` field within). Please paste the twig file that holds the `LivreType` form if you can.

The javascript code is also unnecessary, as you should be able to use the `asset` twig function to import the script from the bundle itself (which is what you have pasted into the twig file). It should, according to [the readme file](https://github.com/blackknight467/StarRatingBundle#step-4-add-the-js), look like so:

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/starrating/js/rating.js') }}"></script>
```

If you want to be able to give rating score while viewing the collection of `Livre` entities, I'm afraid that you need to change the whole approach, there are many ways you can achieve this, e.g. displaying a `RatingType` form instead of just the rating score.

<strike>On another note - I'm not sure if the library you use is working as intended. I haven't tried myself, but from [what I can see](https://github.com/blackknight467/StarRatingBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/rating.html.twig#L10), it seems like the actual value of the rating is incorrect. In the case of 5-star system (so the default) and with clicking 4th star, the code that I've linked would give a value of 2, because in `data-value="{{ stars - star + 1 }}"` the `stars` is `5` and `star` is `4`.</strike>

Actually the code there is correct, it's just that the div elements for stars are added in descending order.

Comment: thank you for your notes , before i put the js in webpage i have already tested it with importing with asset , also the main problem is that the js is not even working (the stars are not mooving) im not in the entity part , and i will paste my livre type is a sec

Comment: FYI you've pasted the `LivreType` form class again. Can you paste the controller that renders the presented twig file?

Comment: Yeah so from what I can see the twig file that is pasted on the top is actually either the `index.html.twig` or the `list.html.twig`, which means that you only show the rating of each persisted `Livre` entity (by using the `|rating` filter), that's why the stars are not moving. I bet however that when you would go to `new.html.twig` or `edit.html.twig`, which render the `LivreType` form, and add the script asset there - then you could actually rate given `Livre` and stars would be moving. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: give me a moment i will try

Comment: i have injected rating in new.html.twig as you suggested i tried with this  {{ '2'|rating }} but i didn't modified the controller , unfortunately the stars still not mooving

Comment: Can you then paste the contents of `new.html.twig`?

Comment: new.html.twig added

Comment: Ok, so the `{{ '2'|rating }}` part in the `new.html.twig` is not necessary. Like I wrote - this one is used to only show the rating, statically, with nothing moving. It is the `form_widget(form)` that should render the stars when rendering the `rating` part of `LivreType`. When you are viewing the `new.html.twig` in the browser - what type of element do you see for the `rating` field of the `form`? Is it just an input field? Or are there stars at it's place?

Comment: the rating in LivreType is commented code like this 
/*  ->add('rating', RatingType::class, ['label' => 'Rating']);*/
because when i add it i got an exception because i ddint added the rating attribute to the entity yet ( i wanted to test the stars before modifing the entity)

an here is a screenshot for the inspect element http://prntscr.com/n8dmmo

Comment: You need to indeed add the `rating` parameter to the `Livre` entity and uncomment the `->add('rating' ...` part. If you do that, then you will see the interactive stars on the `new.html.twig` rendered page. Please try that and let me know if you indeed do see interactive stars then.

Comment: it works !! after adding public $rating; in the entity , i guess the documentation was  bad !, does this will work in the list.html.twig ?

Comment: If you want to actually give rating with those interactive stars while on `list.html.twig`, then you should pass a form type of your own making that will have `RatingType` element in it (just like your `LivreType` does). That would mean you would have to generate that form for each `Livre` in the `listlivreAction()` and render those forms instead of the static rating display. However in that case you would also need to write custom JavaScript that would make a request to submit the individual rating form that was clicked and save the results to the database. Too much to write out here though.

Comment: i have detailed_livre.twig that render 1 entity using the id will that work ? if yes what should i configure except updating the database table and the entity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191372/discussion-between-taib-adhibi-and-michal-tomczuk).

Answer (score 0):

The example on Github writes:
{{ someInteger|rating }}
You write
{{ someInteger|rating() }}

Comment: thats not the problem the stars dosent even change i have tired them both

Answer (score 0):

You need to put 'rating' into the twig template from symfony something like

```
<?php
    // ...
    $builder->add('rating', RatingType::class, [
        //...
        'stars' => 4,
        //...
    ]);
    // ...
```

Comment: i have already did that also , the problem is in the html im calling the js script the wrong way !

Comment: Then please update your question to show your code. rating() is how you call a function in js, so the function isn't on the page somehow.

Comment: calling the function in js is with the class name you are miss understaning here ..

Comment: what do you want to see exactly ?

Comment: The php code you wrote to import the php in the bundle you linked to.

Comment: You still need to import the bundle from php, js and css isn't enough.

Comment: i have updated the twig page so you can understand me

Comment: use blackknight467\StarRatingBundle\Form\RatingType;

Comment: ok, now I can see everything. Try using 4 rather than '4' in {{ '4'|rating }} :)

Comment: the same it will change nothing , the problem is in the class called js  , the stars are non clickable